# Way to add href in row data in table using html

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to display a table that with rows that will include its value in the hyperlink?

```
ReferenceNumber
1234 -> this one is clickable leading to localhost:8080/getDetails/1234
1235
```

Thank you

```
            //Add the data rows from Excel file.
            for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
                //Add the data row.
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                //Add the data cells.
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].ReferenceNumber;
            }
```

Comment: Elaborate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap it in `<a></a>` tag.

```
//Add the data rows from Excel file.
for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
    //Add the data row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    //Add the data cells.
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);

    var link = '<a href="localhost:8080/getDetails/' + excelRows[i].ReferenceNumber + '">' + excelRows[i].ReferenceNumber + '</a>';
    cell.innerHTML = link;
}
```